# UIView Animation completed instantly

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

So I've been working on a personal project, where I wanted to apply everything I have learned, but I have encountered this problem.

I have simplified this problem into this easy app.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

@IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let nextVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nextVC") as! SecondViewController
    nextVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    present(nextVC, animated: true)
}

}
```

However, when I change the view using the button mentioned above, I have set it to do animation under when it loads, but when it does, it is automatically in the final stage of the animation

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var loadingImageView: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 10, animations: {
                   self.loadingImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 400)
               }) { (_) in
                   print("Animation has been done")
           }
}
}
```

Any advice will be appreciated. :)

Comment: Try tp run the animation in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`

Comment: Also suggest you to use https://github.com/MihaelIsaev/UIKitPlus lib

Comment: Always try to do animation in viewDidAppear. Because we would like to animate views for user so user can see them animating. And viewDidAppear get called when view appears to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if moving the animation to viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear like @imike suggested doesn't work, try using transition on the "loadingImageView" instead "animate"

```
 UIView.transition(with: self.loadingImageView,
                     duration: 10,
                     options: [. curveEaseInOut],
                     animations: {

                       self.loadingImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 400)
   },
                     completion: nil)
```

Comment: using viewDidAppear did work :) Thanks everybody for your help! :) Have a nice day